# Javascript: Filter list of objects by a list of filter objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have currently two different lists of objects, one which needs to filter the other. Here is how they currently look.

```
var heroes = [
    {
      name: "warrior",
      primary_skill: "greater bash",
      attack_type: "melee",
      attribute: "strength"
    },
    {
      name: "ranger",
      primary_skill: "focus fire",
      attack_type: "range",
      attribute: "agility"
    },
    {
      name: "mage",
      primary_skill: "oblivion",
      attack_type: "magic",
      attribute: "intelligence"
    },
    {
      name: "soldier",
      primary_skill: "sword dance",
      attack_type: "melee",
      attribute: "strength"
    }
]
```

Which should be filtered by the following

```
var filters = [
    { attack_type: "melee" },
    { attribute: "strength" }
]
```

The filters should work in an "and" fashion, so this would filter the list of heroes so that only melee heroes that have the strength attribute are shown.

Here is the attempt that I have so far, but I'm not making much progress:

```
const filteredHeroes = heroes.filter(
    hero => {
        return filters.some( 
            filter => {
                return filter.attack_type === hero.attack_type &&
                filter.primary_skill === hero.primary_skill &&
                filter.attribute === hero.attribute
            }
        )
    }
)
```

I understand this filter function makes no sense.. But I do not know the correct way to do what I require.

Ideally the function that applies the filters is agnostic about the properties that are included, so that if the data set was to include a new property that isn't currently present, the filters array could accept that and the function that applies them doesn't require any updates.

I do not wish to include any external libraries, backwards compatibility is not a huge concern - as long as it works in IE11 and all other modern browsers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `filter` and `every`

```
heroes.filter( s => //for every object in heroes
    filters.every( t => { //check if every filter in iteration has the same value or not
       var key = Object.keys(t)[0]; 
       return s[key] == t[key]
    })
);
```

**Demo**

```js
var heroes = [{
    name: "warrior",
    primary_skill: "greater bash",
    attack_type: "melee",
    attribute: "strength"
  },
  {
    name: "ranger",
    primary_skill: "focus fire",
    attack_type: "range",
    attribute: "agility"
  },
  {
    name: "mage",
    primary_skill: "oblivion",
    attack_type: "magic",
    attribute: "intelligence"
  },
  {
    name: "soldier",
    primary_skill: "sword dance",
    attack_type: "melee",
    attribute: "strength"
  }
];
var filters = [{
    attack_type: "melee"
  },
  {
    attribute: "strength"
  }
];

var output = heroes.filter(s => filters.every(t => {
  var key = Object.keys(t)[0];
  return s[key] == t[key]
}));

console.log(output);
```

For IE11 compatibility, use normal functions (don't use arrow functions) and [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#Polyfill) for `every`

```
var output = heroes.filter( function(s){ 
     return filters.every( function(t) {
        var key = Object.keys(t)[0];
        return s[key] == t[key]
     });
});
```

Comment: I updated every with some for my own requirement :-D. Good job, dude

Answer (score 3):

I think your data structure is not really appriopriated, `filters` should be an object rather than an array :

```js
const heroes = [
    {
      name: "warrior",
      primary_skill: "greater bash",
      attack_type: "melee",
      attribute: "strength"
    },
    {
      name: "ranger",
      primary_skill: "focus fire",
      attack_type: "range",
      attribute: "agility"
    },
    {
      name: "mage",
      primary_skill: "oblivion",
      attack_type: "magic",
      attribute: "intelligence"
    }
 ];

const filters = { attack_type: "melee", attribute: "strength" };

const filteredHeroes = heroes.filter(hero => 
   Object.keys(filters).every(key => hero[key] === filters[key])
);
 
 console.log(filteredHeroes);
```

Comment: If I was to store my filters like this in my app state, would this not require me to do mutations on the object when it should be immutable? I'm in the process of learning react, so I apologise if this doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

This way also works

```
var output =  heroes.filter(function(hero) {
return hero.attribute == 'strength'&&hero.attack_type== 'melee' ;   


 });
```

```js
var heroes = [{
    name: "warrior",
    primary_skill: "greater bash",
    attack_type: "melee",
    attribute: "strength"
  },
  {
    name: "ranger",
    primary_skill: "focus fire",
    attack_type: "range",
    attribute: "agility"
  },
  {
    name: "mage",
    primary_skill: "oblivion",
    attack_type: "magic",
    attribute: "intelligence"
  },
  {
    name: "soldier",
    primary_skill: "sword dance",
    attack_type: "melee",
    attribute: "strength"
  }
];

var output =  heroes.filter(function(hero) {
 return hero.attribute == 'strength'&&hero.attack_type== 'melee' ; 
  

});


console.log(output);
```